# Numpy doesn't work with 32 bit Python on 64 bit windows

Tags: python, numpy, activepython

I have a Python 2.7.8. 32-bit installed on Windows 10 64 bit. When I try to `import numpy` I get the following error:

```
ActivePython 2.7.8.10 (ActiveState Software Inc.) based on
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jul  2 2014, 19:50:44) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import numpy
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Users\Igic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py", line 137, in <module>
    import add_newdocs
  File "C:\Users\Igic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\add_newdocs.py", line 9, in <module>
    from numpy.lib import add_newdoc
  File "C:\Users\Igic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>

    from type_check import *
  File "C:\Users\Igic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\lib\type_check.py", line 8, in <module>
    import numpy.core.numeric as _nx
  File "C:\Users\Igic\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python27\site-packages\numpy\core\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    import multiarray
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I have installed `numpy-1.9.2+unoptimized-cp27-none-win32.whl` from [this page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [CGohlke's page](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/):

> The binaries are compatible with the official CPython distribution on Windows >=6.0. Chances are they don't work with custom Python distributions included with Blender, Maya, ArcGIS, OSGeo4W, ABAQUS, Cygwin, Pythonxy, Canopy, EPD, Anaconda, WinPython etc.

My guess is that the same is also true of ActivePython.

I would recommend either installing the official CPython Windows binary from [here](https://www.python.org/downloads/windows/), or installing the Anaconda distribution from [here](https://store.continuum.io/cshop/anaconda/), which comes with numpy, scipy, matplotlib and a raft of other scientific Python packages.